# OSX 10.5.8 can't compile for arch i386

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I know is a odd question just becouse the solution is to move to a newer OS, but I would like to give another life to this old machine.

It's a macboolAir with Dual 2 Core, should be a 64bit processor but is reported to be i386 arch. I've installed Xcore 3.1.4 thatcome with gcc 9 (4.0.1).

Now if I try to compile an application I got errors that I don't have on a 10.6 machine:

I've sprited out every option to gcc just to see the cause and this is the result:

```
mc-book-air:squeezelite-r2 macbookair$ i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 output_pa.c -c -o output_pa
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/IOKitLib.h:41,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Headers/DADisk.h:28,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Files.h:62,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Components.h:32,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:85,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Headers/AUComponent.h:21,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Headers/AudioUnit.h:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/pa_mac_core.h:48,
                 from output_pa.c:29:
/usr/include/mach/mach_types.h:117: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_t'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:350: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_t' was here
/usr/include/mach/mach_types.h:177: error: syntax error before 'thread_port_array_t'
output_pa.c: In function '_pa_open':
output_pa.c:290: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pthread_create' from incompatible pointer type
```

output_pa.c contains :

```
#include "squeezelite.h"
#if PORTAUDIO
#include <portaudio.h>
#if OSX
#include <pa_mac_core.h>
#endif
```

where portaudio.h and pa_mac_core.h are headers for libportaudio.a that was compiled in the same system anc contains i386, x86_64, ppc and ppc64 archs.

squeezelite.h is the 'main' application header and contains the:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

I'm confused. Any Idea of what should I look for?

Thanks, Marco.

Comment: It looks like you may have multiple includes of the same file, check the header files you're including and see if any of them include the same file

Comment: That's the oddity. In this case, I'll have the error also compiling in 10.5.6.

Comment: @Ryan Fitzpatrick, but you where rigth! pa_mac_core.h includes portaudio.h... Let's have a try...

Comment: @Ryan Fitzpatrick, Hmm, i've changed the include logic to avoid the double include of portaudio.h, but the problem, as espected, is not here. All the other are System lib, I could do nothin in this regards I suppose.